# Подозрительный файл C:\Windows\D.sys

Tags: windows, windows-10

В папке C:\Windows появился файл D.sys на 10 ГБ, информации о таком файле практически нет в интернете, единственное, что нашёл - то, что это драйвер устройства. Но такого файла никогда не было и никаких новых устройств я не подключал. Этот файл не видно в проводнике, даже если включить отображение скрытых файлов. Нашёл его с помощью программы-анализатора дискового пространства, удалить его невозможно "открыт в другой программе", через командную строку пишет, что файл не найдет. Пробовал загружаться с флешки, там этот файл отображается, удалил его, но он создаётся при каждом запуске. В Process Monitor ничего не нашёл .

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1805780 - здесь в комментариях предполагают, что это файл VeraCrypt.

Comment: драйвер должен быть подписан, посмотрите в свойствах, наверняка нет подписи

Comment: В Process Monitor пробовал отслеживать процессы во время загрузки ничего нет связанного с этим файлом, но он каждый раз создаётся, в мониторе ресурсов тоже нет инфы, что он где-то открыт.

Comment: Для определения процесса, использующего файл, обычно используют другую консольную MS утилиту (от Sysinternals): [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle): `handle C:\Windows\D.sys`. В Вашем случае лучше запускать хотя бы от администратора.